# Ionic 2 / 3 - How to view 2 slides when screen is wide?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I searched about something that allows me to view 1 ion-slide if the screen of device is small, else it should be 2 ion-slide but I couldn't find the solution

For example I used this code to view 1 slide and part of other slide

```
<ion-slides slidesPerView="1.125">
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

And this other code allows me to view 2 slides

```
<ion-slides slidesPerView="2.125">
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

My question is possible to make such as bellow image-example in ionic & How ?

[image: view 2 slides in wide screens]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hard work and so many tests, I could find the best solution as I think..

Here is my solution

First of all I wrote a function that check the screen width and return 1.125 or 2.125

```
checkScreen(){
    if(window.innerWidth>=960){
        return 2.125;
    }else{
        return 1.125;
    }
}
```

Then I made these few changes in the HTML

```
<ion-content (ionChange)="checkScreen()">
    <ion-slides [slidesPerView]="checkScreen()">
        <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 1</h1>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <h1>Slide 2</h1>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

Now the slides shows in different shapes dependent on screen size

Answer (score 1):

You must do it programmatically. And it is better to do for all cases:

- resize
- orientationchange

So you may have Device class, which will be able to check device type,
using UA regex (maybe it is not needed but I have seen good example on github).

```
interface DeviceData {
  widht:number;
  type:any;
  orientation:any;
}

class Device{

  public onRezise = new EventEmitter();
  public onOrientationChange = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(){

    //add listeners for resize and orientation change
  }

  public getWidth(){

  }

  public getOrientation(){

  }

  public getDeviceType(){

  }
}
```

Then you can use data in your component, also listen to changes in window.
And have dynamic number of slides.

```
   class Component {
      constructor(private _device:Device){

      }

      ngOnInit(){
        this._device.onOrientationChange.subscribe((v:DeviceData) => this.setNumberOfSlides(v));
        this._device.onRezise.subscribe((v:DeviceData) => this.setNumberOfSlides(v));
      }

      private setNumberOfSlides(data:DeviceData){
        this._numberOfSlides = data.widht/slideWidth;
      }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried to test it but I don't where is the problem, I got errors... any way, I got the best and easiest selution

Comment: This is just code structure example, not working proto. So you may provide Device class to angular DI and use it in components. In this class you need to add event listeners for resize and orientation change (depending on needs). Then subscribe to this events, and just set proper number of slides depending on width/orientation etc.

Comment: Yes, I tried to follow the structure but I got so many problems. You can check/see my solution now (maybe you have any comments)... thanks for your helps :)